# How to initialize derived class from static method's return object?

Tags: php, oop

How can I initialize class' base class by return value in construct? Let's say I have this as a base class:

```
class Base
{
    public function Foo()
    {
    }

    private $_var;
}
```

I also have this one static method from another class, which returns Base class:

```
class MyStaticClass
{
    public static function Get()
    {
        return new Base();
    }
}
```

and now I derive from base class it here:

```
class Derived extends Base
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Here, how can I initialize Base class with
        // object MyStaticClass returns? Something like

        parent = MyStaticClass::Get(); // This doesn't obviously work..
    }
}
```

Is there any solution / workaround to this?

Comment: If you have the need to do this... it seems that you need to re-think your architectural design. Why would you want to change the parent of a class during it's construction after it's after been declared as extending another class ? Can you give some contextual example ?

Answer (score 0):

Though it seems like an uncommon way of doing it, you probably mean this:

```
class Derived extends Base
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(MyStaticClass::Get());
    }
}
```

Comment: But the Base-class does not have constructor. Does this still work?

Comment: Probably you should define `Base`'s copy constructor accepting `Base` type as a parameter

Comment: Every class has a constructor. If `Base` only has the default constructor (which I assumed not), then this will not work, since the default constructor doesn't accept any arguments. `Base`'s constructor needs a parameter of type `Base` then.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to directly do that, but if you are willing to let go of `class`, you can accomplish this with javascript-style OOP. See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10468793/1369091