# PHP Class Extends a string variable

Tags: php, class

Is it possible to declare a class and have it extend a variable?

```
class Child extends $parentClass {}
```

Comment: as long as its a public variable. You should be good. ALso remove `$` from parentClass

Comment: No, this does not work!

Comment: `$parentClass = new stdClass(); eval("class Child extends $parentClass {}");` ha ha harrr never use `eval`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to extend a class dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539530/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-class-dynamically)

Comment: Please before more up-vote of this question. Explain what the content of `$parentClass` is? An instance of an class or an name of a class as string?

Comment: $parentClass is a string like "Parent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no you cant.

this is because in a normal definition:

```
class A extends SomeOtherClass {
}
```

SomeOtherClass is a namespace reference, not an instance of the class. And you cant use a variable to provide that namespace because variables in PHP are defined at runtime, whereas classes are defined in the compile phase.

But... if youre using PHP7, you can do this:

```
$newClass = new class extends SomeOtherClass {};
```

which is not exactly what you want, but goes some way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is with eval. But it is not recommended.

```
<?php
function dynamic_class_name() {
    if(time() % 60)
        return "Class_A";
    if(time() % 60 == 0)
        return "Class_B";
}
eval(
    "class MyRealClass extends " . dynamic_class_name() . " {" . 
    # some code string here, possibly read from a file
    . "}"
);
?>
```

Is Eval an evil?! [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I hope my answer helps someone.
You can use `class_alias()` to an "intermediate" class:

```
class_alias($parentClass, 'ParentClassAlias');
class Child extends ParentClassAlias {}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Class can not extend from a variable , You need to wrap the variable inside a class to extend . Hope this helps