# php aliasing a type using a variable

Tags: php, namespaces

I have several namespaces, which have their own exception handlers.
I also have a general script which needs to reference one of exception handlers - the namespace required is held in a global string.

```
namespace myNamespace1;
class NewException extends \Exception
{
    ....
}
```

- 

```
namespace myNamespace2;
class NewException extends \Exception
{
    ....
}
```

The $ref variable is a string containing myNamespace1 or myNamespace2. I want to alias one of the Exceptions using this global variable

```
global $ref;
$alias = $ref . "\NewException";
define("ex", $alias);
use ex as EX;
```

This doesn't give an error until I try to throw an EX. The class can then not be loaded.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I would say yes but not recommended check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612215/php-class-extends-a-string-variable/43612644

Answer (score 0):

In `use ex as EX;` `ex` is treated as class name, you can't use constants or variables in this way. If you want to alias class name, you can use [`class_alias()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php):

```php
global $ref;
class_alias($ref . '\NewException', 'my\Exception');

// ...

throw new \my\Exception();
```

Note that you can have only one `class_alias()` call that defines `my\Exception`, and this alias will be available in other places of project.